# Let $\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\}$ be distinct elements in the set $\{ -7 , -5 , -3 , -2 , 2 , 4 , 6 , 13 \}$ .

Tags: functions

Let $\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\}$ be distinct elements in the set$ \{ -7 , -5 , -3 , -2 , 2 , 4 , 6 , 13 \}$ . The minimum possible value of $(a+b+c+d)^2 + (e+f+g+h)^2$ is ?

I tried it by making the first term zero by merging $-3+4$ and $-7$ and $6$ but it does not seem to help because still my value is coming to be 49 and the options are : $30 , 32 , 34 , 40$

Comment: Hint: $x^2 + y^2$ is minimal for fixed $x + y$, if $x$ and $y$ are as equal as possible. So instead of making one sum zero, try to get them to have as similar values as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the set is 8.  You want to get as close as possible to $4^2 + 4^2 = 32$.  If this can't be achieved, the next best case would be $3^2 + 5^2 = 34$, etc.

This is because of an important property of the square function, called convexity (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function)

Comment: Thanks i got it .. i forgot that i should make functions equal rather than making them zero